# Why are some images not rendering

Tags: php, mysql, image

My program uploads images of various sizes into the blob field of a MySQL database using PHP. I was able to successfully upload different sizes up to 1MB and above. My problem is that when I display them, I was able to display images that are less than 10KB. For larger images, an error is displayed ***..... cannot be displayed because it contains errors*** (in Firefox), and in Chrome, it simply shows an image placeholder. I have tried so many tricks, and I have googled everywhere. I edited both php.ini and my.ini.  My program is an intranet application, and there will be less than 50 users at a time. This is the script that is used to display the images:

If I remove the header ('Content-Type: '.$resource_type), it dumps the binary code on the screen. I have increase the MySQL packet size to 100MB, and the problem persists.

```
    $d_id= $_GET['k'];$query="";$query_handle=0;$row="";$no_of_rows=0;
    $query="SELECT * FROM tdoc ";
    $query.=" WHERE ucase(trim(fsha_doc_key))='".strtoupper(trim($d_id))."' ";
    $query_handle=mysql_query($query,$conn_handle);
    if(!$query_handle) {$error_flag=1;echo '<br />Unable to execute query to Extract Resource CODE:FREF';}
    if($query_handle) $no_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_handle);
    if(($query_handle)&&($no_of_rows<=0)) {$error_flag=1;echo '<br />The Exact Resource: '.strip_tags($d_id).' NOT found ';}
    if(($query_handle)&&($no_of_rows>0)){
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_handle);
        $resource_type=trim($row['ftype']);
        $resource_size=$row['fsize'];
        $resource_h=$row['fheight'];
        $resource_w=$row['fwidth'];
        $d_resource=$row['fdoc'];
        header('Content-Type: '.$resource_type);
        header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
        header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
        header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($d_resource));
        header('Content-height: '.$resource_h);
        header('Content-width: '.$resource_w);
        echo stripslashes(base64_decode($d_resource));
    }
```

I have read exclusively posts concerning this error here, but none address my specific issue, because mine is displaying small size images but not images up to and above 10kb. 10kb is a far cry from my projected average image size that would be uploaded later. Please help.

Comment: This looks like you might be opening yourself to SQL injection?

Comment: just a suggestion, you shouldn't save entire files in your database,  you should save it in a directory on your server and then reference the link the file in msql...

Answer (score 0):

If `$d_resource` is binary image data

You should used imagejpeg or imagegif or other series functions, rather than `echo`

See [Output image to browser or file - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change the type from `BLOB` (or even `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`?) to `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`, see the [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

```
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT  L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8
BLOB, TEXT  L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT  L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT  L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32
```

The size for `BLOB` is 2^16, but the actual size is smaller since you `base64_encode` the images (it is not nesessary if you use BLOB which stores binary data).

Also note John's comment to your question: you should add slashes to `$d_id` if you don't have `magic_quotes_gpc` on.

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting the memory limit because you are carrying around multiple copies of the image. One in $row[fdoc], one in $d_resources. And you should probably remove the stripslashes call, its not doing you any favors.